# Add a permanent contour line to a surface plot in R plotly

Tags: r, plotly, contour, r-plotly, surface

I am using the `plotly` package in R to draw a surface plot and a contour plot:

```
# Load package
library(plotly)

# Simulate the data for plotting
x <- y <- seq(from = 0, to = 100, by = 1)
z1 <- outer(X = x, Y = y, FUN = function(x, y) x^0.2 * y^0.3) # data for surface plot

# Draw surface plot (3D)
plotly::plot_ly(z = z1) %>%
  plotly::add_surface(
    contours = list(
      z = list(
        show = TRUE,
        usecolormap = TRUE,
        highlightcolor = "#ff0000",
        project = list(z = TRUE)
      ) 
    )    
  ) 

# Draw contour plot (2D)
plot_ly(z = z1) %>%
  add_contour()
```

The rendering of the two plots contains contour lines, which show the combinations of `x` and `y` that yield a constant `z` level. In the case of the 3D surface plot, hovering the mouse over it dynamically draws a contour line where the mouse is with a projection of the contour line on one of the sides of the 3-dimensional space.

What I would like to do is to manually draw one or multiple contour lines on the two plots by specifying a value for `z` myself (e.g. `z = 5`).

Comment: You might find the code in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61779969/r-plotly-show-string-on-contour-plots to be helpful, despite that fact that no one answered the question. The questioner showed how to get contour lines are specific levels of z.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @IRTFM's comment, I was able to find an answer to my question. The answer is more specific to contour plots. The user needs to set the `start` and `end` attributes under the `contours` argument to the desired `z` value. Below, I plot the contour line for `z = 5`:

```
# Load package
library(plotly)

# Simulate the data for plotting
x <- y <- seq(from = 0, to = 100, by = 1)
z1 <- outer(X = x, Y = y, FUN = function(x, y) x^0.2 * y^0.3) # data for surface plot

plot_ly(
  z = z1,
  type = "contour",
  autocontour = FALSE,    
  colorscale = "RdBu",
  
  contours = list(
    start = 5,
    end = 5,
    showlabels = TRUE,
    showlines = TRUE,
    coloring = "lines"
  )
  
) %>%
 hide_guides()
```

[image: Contour line z = 5]

In case one wants to plot 2 specific contour lines, they need an additional argument: `ncontours = 2`. Not doing so will likely lead to the plotting of more than 2 contour lines - the lines for which the `z` value is between `start` and `end`.

```
plot_ly(
  z = z1,
  type = "contour",
  autocontour = FALSE,
  
  ncontours = 2,
  
  colorscale = "RdBu",
  
  contours = list(
    start = 5,
    end = 7,
    showlabels = TRUE,
    showlines = TRUE,
    coloring = "lines"
  )
  
) %>%
 hide_guides()
```

[image: Two contour lines, z=5 and z=7]

Finally, for more than 2 specific contour lines, we need to use the `add_contour()` function. Let's plot 4 specific contour plots:

```
plot_ly(
  z = z1,
  type = "contour",
  autocontour = FALSE,
  
  ncontours = 2,
  
  colorscale = "RdBu",
  
  contours = list(
    start = 5,
    end = 7,
    showlabels = TRUE,
    showlines = TRUE,
    coloring = "lines"
  )
  
) %>% 
  
  add_contour(
    
    ncontours = 2,
    
    contours = list(
      start = 4,
      end = 6,
      showlabels = TRUE,
      showlines = TRUE,
      coloring = "lines"
    )
    
  ) %>%
  
  hide_guides()
```

[image: Four contour plots]