# Find the exact coordinates of a contour on a surface and plot it manually in R plotly

Tags: r, plotly, contour, r-plotly, surface

I am drawing a surface plot and would like to "manually" draw a contour line using `plotly`. In the code below I:

- simulate the data for drawing the surface plot
- calculate the coordinates of the contour line at a specific z level using the `contoureR` package
- draw the surface plot and contour line

```
# Load packages
library(plotly) # for interactive visualizations
library(contoureR) # for calculating contour coordinates

# Simulate the data for plotting
x <- y <- seq(from = 0, to = 100, by = 1)
z1 <- outer(X = x, Y = y, FUN = function(x, y) x^0.2 * y^0.3) # data for surface plot

# Obtain coordinates of contour for z = 5
z_level <- 5
r <- contourLines(x = x, y = y, z = z1, levels = z_level)

plot_ly(
  type = "surface",
  x = x,
  y = y,
  z = z1,
) %>%
  add_trace(
    type = "scatter3d",
    x = r[[1]]$x,
    y = r[[1]]$y,
    z = z_level
  )
```

[image: contour_line1]

I am aware that these are all approximations, so I also tried to pass the `x` and `y` coordinates produced by `contourLines()` to the formula used to create `z1`above and use the corresponding values to plot my contour line (instead of using `z_level = 5`, but I still do not obtain the desired result:

```
plot_ly(
  x = x,
  y = y,
  z = z1,
  type = "surface"
) %>%
  add_trace(
    type = "scatter3d",
    x = r[[1]]$x,
    y = r[[1]]$y,
    z = r[[1]]$x^0.2*r[[1]]$y^0.3
  )
```

[image: contour_line2]

I alo know that `plotly` enables me to draw specific contour lines (see my question and answer here: [Add a permanent contour line to a surface plot in R plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65349844/add-a-permanent-contour-line-to-a-surface-plot-in-r-plotly?noredirect=1#comment115534028_65349844)). However, I would like to draw my contour line myself (after getting their coordinates) so it can "pull" by cursor and show me the tooltip info whenever I hover over it. Ideally, if there was a way to obtain the contour lines coordinates as computed by `plotly` itself, that would be great.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find two solutions to this problem.

## Solution 1: transpose the `z1` matrix

The first solution was given me by @nirgrahamuk and it consists in transposing the `z1` matrix:

```
library(plotly) # for interactive visualizations

# Simulate the data for plotting
x <- y <- seq(from = 0, to = 100, by = 1)
z1 <- outer(X = x, Y = y, FUN = function(x, y) x^0.2 * y^0.3) # data for surface plot

# Obtain coordinates of contour for z = 5
z_level <- 6
r <- contourLines(x = x, 
                  y = y, 
                  z = z1, 
                  levels = z_level)

plot_ly(
  type = "surface",
  z = t(z1), # *** WE TRANSPOSE THE MATRIX HERE! ***
) %>%
  add_trace(
    type = "scatter3d",
    x = r[[1]]$x,
    y = r[[1]]$y,
    z = z_level
  )
```

## Solution 2: use the `isoband` package

The second solution is to compute the contour lines coordinates with the `isoband::isolines()` function:

```
library(plotly) # for interactive visualizations
library(isoband) # for find contour lines coordinates

# Simulate the data for plotting
x <- y <- seq(from = 0, to = 100, by = 1)
z1 <- outer(X = x, Y = y, FUN = function(x, y) x^0.2 * y^0.3) # data for surface plot

# Obtain coordinates of contour for z = 5
z_level <- 6
r <- isolines(x = x, # *** WE USE THE isolines() FUNCTION HERE ***
              y = y, 
              z = z1, 
              levels = z_level)

plot_ly(
  type = "surface",
  z = z1, 
) %>%
  add_trace(
    type = "scatter3d",
    x = r[[1]]$x,
    y = r[[1]]$y,
    z = z_level
  )
```